# How can I display a chromatogram as an image?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, biojava

I'm working with the 1.8.1 release of biojava on Netbeans, and using the *ChromatogramGraphic* Class to try to create an image of a chromatogram. 
(http://www.biojava.org/docs/api1.8/)

I've made a file chooser to access chromatograms, and I use the *ChromatogramFactory* (from biojava) Class to create a Chromatogram Object from the file.

Apparently, this:

http://biojava.org/pipermail/biojava-l/2003-June/003896.html

code can accomplish what I want. I don't understand what it does, and I don't think I can use similar syntax to draw the image on my JFrame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[What I have so far. I don't know what most of it does.]

```
    private void renderTrace() throws IOException, UnsupportedChromatogramFormatException {
    ABIFChromatogram abiChrom = new ABIFChromatogram();

    File abi = new File(textarea.getText());

    ABITrace abiTrace = new ABITrace(abi);
    ABIFParser abiParse = new ABIFParser(abi);
    ChromatogramFactory chromFactory = new ChromatogramFactory();


    Chromatogram chrom = ChromatogramFactory.create(abi);


    ChromatogramGraphic gfx = new ChromatogramGraphic(chrom);

    gfx.setHeight(240);
    gfx.setHorizontalScale(2.0f);
     // set some options that affect the output
    // turn off filled-in "callboxes"
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_A,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_C,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_G,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_T,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_OTHER,
            Boolean.FALSE);
     // this option controls whether each trace/callbox/etc is scaled/positioned
    // individually, or whether the scaling is done on all shapes at the level
    // of the graphics context
    // enabling this option is recommended for higher-quality output

    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.USE_PER_SHAPE_TRANSFORM,
            Boolean.TRUE);

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                               gfx.getWidth(), 
                               gfx.getHeight(), 
                               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    g2.setBackground(Color.white);
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
    if (g2.getClip() == null) {
        g2.setClip(new Rectangle(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight()));
    }
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    // the main event
    gfx.drawTo(g2);
    // work-around an OS X bug where sometimes the last Shape drawn
    // doesn't show up in the output
    g2.draw(new java.awt.Rectangle(-10, -10, 5, 5));


    gfx.drawTo();


}
```

Comment: [link](http://biojava.org/pipermail/biojava-l/2003-June/003896.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this works then you can draw the image using the paint() method of JFrame. First you need to make sure that this

```
gfx.drawTo(g2);
```

works, from the gfx side. Try to save the image into a file and see if its there

```
try {
  ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("gfx-image.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

with import javax.imageio.*; in your import statements.

If that works and you can see the image then at the JFrame you need to have something like

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Comment: I added the following `try {
  ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("gfx-image.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }` but I dont know what it does. How do I know if the picture was created?

Comment: it should save the image to the file "gfx-image.png" at your current directory; check to see if an image with that name has been created - after you run the program

Comment: It worked! [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nGPfKaY21KeWtaRTdySXlYQmM/view?usp=sharing) I have the photo. I'm sorry to bother you so much, but I'm very new to this. How can I draw this on my JFrame? Also, the picture is very long (2018 nucleotides long), so how can I make it scrollable side to side? @gpasch nvm, EDIT the question has been answered. I'll look up the answer to this second part elsewhere, thank you!

Comment: if you post your JFrame code to your question I can probably answer it - but the scrollable thing is a bit more trouble - it cant be done in this question - just open up a new question once we have this done

Comment: I'll open a new question about it because I can't find a related question. I'll also post a picture of my JFrame and relevant source code (It's difficult to add siginficant amounts of code in comments)